# What is the simplest way to connect hosts on the same subnet?

Tags: networking, routing, ethernet, bridge

I would like to achieve that what ever hosts (that are on the same subnet) I connect on ethx on tunx, could see (ping, have ip connection) the other ones located on the the other ethx or tunx (on the same subnet). This seems to be not possible with the bridge, any suggestions? (Not something like openvswitch, something simple/small)

```
               +-----------+           
               |    BR0    |      10.11.12.x     
   172.16.1.y  |           |      172.16.1.x
       --------|ETH2   TUN1|-------           
               |           |           
               |           |      172.16.1.x
    10.11.12.y |       TUN2|-------           
       --------|ETH1       |
               +-----------+
```

In this situation below I can ping a vm from br0 connected to 172.16.1.y

```
               +-----------+           
               |    BR0    |           
   172.16.1.y  |           |      172.16.1.x
       --------|ETH2   TUN1|-------           
               |           |           
               |           |      172.16.1.x
               |       TUN2|-------           
               |           |
               +-----------+
```

When only adding a 2nd eth adapter with 'brctl addif br0 eth1' connected to 10.11.12.y. The same ping is not working anymore. I learned this is because the bridge mac changes to the newly added eth1s mac changing it back with 'ifconfig br0 hw ether ' to eth2 restablishes the connection with 172.16.1.y.

```
               +-----------+           
               |    BR0    |           
   172.16.1.y  |           |      172.16.1.x
       --------|ETH2   TUN1|-------           
               |           |           
               |           |      172.16.1.x
    10.11.12.y |       TUN2|-------           
       --------|ETH1       |
               +-----------+
```

The problem is that I seem to be only able to ping either 10.11.12.y or 172.16.1.y even with try to force arp updates with 'arping -I br0 -s 10.11.12.158 10.11.12.1' or setting dedicated entries in the arp table.

Theoritically it should be possible to bridge multiple subnets over a bridge?

UPDATE:
I have BR0 vm in vmware and someone from the Linux Advanced Routing & Traffic Control mailing list told me that vswitch of vmware is likely to cause eth1 and eth2 to behave differently. Eg. my config should already working.

Comment: i dont want to route between the subnets, the hosts on the subnet (including the ip on the bridge need to be able to see each other

Comment: Either you need to route or all the hosts need to be in the same subnet. Your call.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot bridge different subnets of a routed protocol such as IP. You can bridge two (or more) of the same subnet. You can route between two (or more) different subnets.

If you want machines on subnet A to be able to contact machines on subnet B you need to route between them. The bridge won't help.

Comment: bridging is done at level 2 not? what ever hosts I am connecting on interface tunx, ethx, should be able to connect to other hosts in the same subnet on a different interface tunx, ethx

Comment: @f1outsourcing if you're using a non-routed protocol this is true. For a routed protocol (L3) such as IP this simply isn't possible unless you're going to futz around with proxy arp and the like.